# Bigdata questions regarding video to numeric data, missing numbers in asequence and visually represents 1 billion data?

Tags: database, bigdata

1. How do you represent a cctv video of 1 sec as numerical data?
2. If you have a single column db table with 10 billion rows of continuously incrementing numbers then explain how you will find missing numbers in the sequence?
3. How do you visually represent 1 billion events on a single dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

1. The key is to index all the activity in the video as it happens – people walking, cars driving, colors, directions.  --

The indexing algorithm is the heart of the solution and it needs to achieve two opposing aims.

Firstly, it must be extremely sensitive and accurate – detecting the smallest important motion in the video and recording it correctly in the search index and missing nothing important even when the video quality is poor.

2. Find the minimum sequence number and maximum sequence number and build the level as a hierarchical query as a derived Dataset.  Find the difference between with the original data set and the derived dataset to find the missing numbers.

Comment: For answer 2: can you please explain it a bit further? What it will contain in the derived data set? and also one more thing we will get the range of missing sequence or the list of all missing sequence number as output?